# Get a particular cell value from HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get each cell value from an HTML table using JavaScript when pressing submit button.

How to get HTML table cell values?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To get the text from this cell-

```
<table>
    <tr id="somerow">
        <td>some text</td>            
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use this -

```
var Row = document.getElementById("somerow");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(Cells[0].innerText);
```

Comment: and how to get column name and row name ?

Comment: this works for a small table but what about my use case where I have a table populated by data from a database using php the data is about 120 rows now but keeps increasing daily. How can I implement this

Answer (score 5):

```
function Vcount() {
var modify = document.getElementById("C_name1").value;
var oTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
var i;
var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++) {
    var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
    if (modify == oCells[0].firstChild.data) {
        document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "  * duplicate value";
        return false;
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var table = document.getElementById("someTableID"); 
var totalRows = document.getElementById("someTableID").rows.length;
var totalCol = 3; // enter the number of columns in the table minus 1 (first column is 0 not 1)
//To display all values
for (var x = 0; x <= totalRows; x++)
  {
  for (var y = 0; y <= totalCol; y++)
    {
    alert(table.rows[x].cells[y].innerHTML;
    }
  }
//To display a single cell value enter in the row number and column number under rows and cells below:
var firstCell = table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
alert(firstCell);
//Note:  if you use <th> this will be row 0, so your data will start at row 1 col 0
```

Comment: Not "x <= totalRows", should be "x < totalRows" otherwise it goes out of bounds of the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the DOM way to obtain the cell value: 
**Cells[0].firstChild.data**

Read more on that in my post at http://js-code.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-change-html-table-cell-value.html

Answer (score 2):

You can get cell value with JS even when click on the cell:

```
.......................

      <head>

        <title>Search students by courses/professors</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
        {
           if (highLight){
               tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '00CCCC';
           }

        else{
             tableRow.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }   
      }

      function DoNav(theUrl)
      {
      document.location.href = theUrl;
      }
      </script>

    </head>
    <body>

         <table id = "c" width="180" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                <% for (Course cs : courses){ %>

                <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
                    onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
                    onclick="DoNav('http://localhost:8080/Mydata/ComplexSearch/FoundS.jsp?courseId=<%=cs.getCourseId()%>');">

                     <td name = "title" align = "center"><%= cs.getTitle() %></td>

                </tr>
               <%}%>

    ........................
    </body>
```

I wrote the HTML table in JSP.
**Course** is is a type. For example Course cs, cs= object of type Course which had 2 attributes: id, title.
**courses** is an ArrayList of Course objects.

The HTML table displays all the courses titles in each cell. So the table has 1 column only:
Course1
Course2
Course3
......
Taking aside:

```
onclick="DoNav('http://localhost:8080/Mydata/ComplexSearch/FoundS.jsp?courseId=<%=cs.getCourseId()%>');"
```

This means that after user selects a table cell, for example "Course2", the title of the course- "Course2" will travel to the page where the URL is directing the user: `http://localhost:8080/Mydata/ComplexSearch/FoundS.jsp`  . "Course2" will arrive in FoundS.jsp page. The identifier of "Course2" is courseId. To declare the variable courseId, in which CourseX will be kept, you put a "?" after the URL and next to it the identifier.

I told you just in case you'll want to use it because I searched a lot for it and I found questions like mine. But now I found out from teacher so I post where people asked.

The example is working.I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply.. #sometime when larger table we can't add the id to each tr

```
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>some text</td>
            <td>something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>Hel</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        var cell = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
        var i = 0;
        while(cell[i] != undefined){
            alert(cell[i].innerHTML); //do some alert for test
            i++;
            }//end while
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class="virtualTd" onclick="putThis(this)">my td value </td>

function putThis(control) { 
    alert(control.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found this as an easiest way to add row . The awesome thing about this is that it doesn't change the already present table contents even if it contains input elements .

```
row = `<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>`
$("#table_body tr:last").after(row) ;
```

Here `#table_body` is the id of the table body tag .

Answer (score 0):

Here is perhaps the simplest way to obtain the value of a single cell.

```
document.querySelector("#table").children[0].children[r].children[c].innerText
```

where r is the row index and c is the column index

Therefore, to obtain all cell data and put it in a multi-dimensional array:

```
var tableData = [];  
Array.from(document.querySelector("#table").children[0].children).forEach(function(tr){tableData.push(Array.from(tr.children).map(cell => cell.innerText))}); 
var cell = tableData[1][2];//2nd row, 3rd column
```

To access a specific cell's data in this multi-dimensional array, use the standard syntax: array[rowIndex][columnIndex].

Answer (score -1):

Make a javascript function

```js
function addSampleTextInInputBox(message) {
    //set value in input box
    document.getElementById('textInput').value = message + "";
    //or show an alert
    //window.alert(message);
}
```

Then simply call in your table row button click

```html
<td class="center">
    <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="addSampleTextInInputBox('<?php echo $row->message; ?>')" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add">
        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```