# How can I get each value in <td> so I can compare it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
 <table id="table_append">
    <tr class='text-center'>" +
         <td>1</td>     
         <td class="codeverify">025</td>  
         <td> Data1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center'>" +
         <td>2</td>     
         <td class="codeverify">036</td>  
         <td> Data2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center'>" +
         <td>3</td>     
         <td class="codeverify">044</td>  
         <td> Data2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to check if the code is on table, and so my javascript function is like this.
Suppose if function find code in table, it will return value true

```
   function codevvy(code) {

    $('.codeverify').each($('.codeverify'), function (index,e) {
        var repo =$(e).text();
        if (repo == code) {
            return false;
        }
        else { return true;}
    });
```

And then I got this error from browser when I debug

> jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.apply is not a function

It seems that my jquery is wrong but I can't find the solution

How can I get each value in td so I can compare it ?

Comment: Have a look at: [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), [jQuery Lerning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: Delete second array: $('.codeverify').each(function (index,e) {...

Comment: please refer this link which might help you[how to get the HTML TABLE Particullar Cell Value using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253558/how-to-get-the-html-table-particullar-cell-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `.each` does not need to select objects again, just feed it the function:

```
function codevvy(code) {
    let result = false; // for not found
    $('.codeverify').each(function (index,e) {
        let repo =$(e).text();
        if (repo == code) {
            result = true;
            return false; // no unneeded iterations after a match is found
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

You may need to normalize both pieces of text in the comparison before the actual comparison to make sure you're comparing the same case/style/whitespace etc.

Comment: no `return` from `codevvy()` here...will always return undefined

Comment: You we're right, I fixed that, thanks. Probably should upvote @DontVoteMeDown's answer instead anyway though; it **is** better.

Comment: FYI - use `return false` to break an `each`

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the incorrect syntax of adding the collection twice to your `each` ... `return` inside `each`does not return to the outer function and you aren't returning anything from `codevvy()`

Can use `filter()` for this and return the length of collection found

```
 function codevvy(code) {
     return  $('.codeverify').filter( function (index,e) {
          return $(this).text() === code
     }).length > 0;
 }
```

You might also be able to use `:contains` selector. Note this isn't an absolute match

```
function codevvy(code)
     return $('.codeverify:contains(' + code + ')').length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
function codevvy(code) {
    var result = false;
  
    $('#table_append .codeverify').each(function () {
        var repo = $(this).text();
        if (repo == code) {
            result = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
  
    return result;
}

console.log(codevvy("025"))
console.log(codevvy("045"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_append">
    <tr class='text-center'>
         <td>1</td>     
         <td class="codeverify">025</td>  
         <td> Data1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center'>
         <td>2</td>     
         <td class="codeverify">036</td>  
         <td> Data2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='text-center'>
         <td>3</td>     
         <td class="codeverify">044</td>  
         <td> Data2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some points on the javascript above:

- You don't return a value from an `each()` loop. That is why I used a var called `result` to return *outside* it. The `return` inside the `each` will only break it;
- You can use `this` inside the `each` loop since you're running it over an html collection.

Comment: Good answer + example + detailed style explanation, would've given +3 if I could

Comment: thank you for fast respond, that's what i mean to do. I just realize that my funct didn't return outside .each loop. Beginner and ESL though, so forgive me if my question is too shallow

Comment: @KokoriNut no problem my friend. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for your eachloop:

```
$('.codeverify').each(function (index,e) {
    var repo =$(e).text();
    if (repo == code) {
        return false;
    }
    else { return true;}
});
```

Comment: return inside `each` doesn't return to the outer function

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.each($('.codeverify'), function (index,e) {}
```

Instead of this:

```
$('.codeverify').each($('.codeverify'), function (index,e) {}
```